# Camunda bpm - How add multiple admin users?

Tags: java, spring-boot, camunda

I’m working on camunda CMMN project and I would like to create multiple admin users from   `src/main/resources/application.yaml`.

So this is my `application.yaml` file :

```
camunda.bpm:
  admin-user:
    id: demo
    password: demo
    firstName: Demo
    lastName: Demo
  filter:
    create: All tasks
```

How could I add more admin users ?

Answer (score 4):

As said in the Camunda documentation in [User Management](https://docs.camunda.org/manual/7.13/webapps/admin/user-management/#administrator-account), "*users who belong to the group camunda-admin have administrator privileges*".

You have 4 ways to create an user with all permissions as shown in [Authorization Management](https://docs.camunda.org/manual/7.13/webapps/admin/authorization-management/#create-a-user-with-all-permissions) :

1. Adding users in the `camunda-admin` group as shown above.
2. Configure the [Administrator Authorization Plugin](https://docs.camunda.org/manual/7.13/user-guide/process-engine/authorization-service/#the-administrator-authorization-plugin), to grant user or group of users all permissions.
3. Create your own group (see [Group Management](https://docs.camunda.org/manual/7.13/webapps/admin/group-management/#groups-menu)) with all permissions granted and assign it to the users you want.
4. Simply grant one specific user all permissions.

Finally, to add multiple users within a specific group in your `application.yaml`, you can have a look at this [Github post](https://github.com/secureCodeBox/engine/pull/115).